# PHP __autoload() doesn't work when class is instantiated from inside an anonymous function

Tags: php, joomla, slim

I'm using Slim PHP framework in conjunction with Joomla. With Slim framework I am creating a REST service e.g.

```
$app->post('/api/users', function() {
    ..trying to instantiate class here..    
});
```

Joomla uses the `jimport()` function to import files (`jimport()` links to `register()`);

```
    function & register ($class = null, $file = null)
        {
            static $classes;

            if(!isset($classes)) {
                $classes    = array();
            }

            if($class && is_file($file))
            {
                // Force to lower case.
                $class = strtolower($class);
                $classes[$class] = $file;

                // In php4 we load the class immediately.
                if((version_compare( phpversion(), '5.0' ) < 0)) {
                    JLoader::load($class);
                }

            }

            return $classes;
        }

function load( $class )
    {
        $class = strtolower($class); //force to lower case

        if (class_exists($class)) {
              return;
        }

        $classes = JLoader::register();
        if(array_key_exists( strtolower($class), $classes)) {
            include($classes[$class]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So instead of actually including the file straight away, it returns the classes array so only when the class is instantiated does the PHP `__autoload()` function get called:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(JLoader::load($class)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So this works fine normally. The problem happens when I instantiate the class inside the anonymous function above, PHP never calls the `__autoload()` function - so the class is never included.

Is it possible to autoload classes upon instantiation inside an anonymous function?

Comment: If the `JLoader` class is declared in the same file then yes.

Comment: `JLoader` is called fine - i'm talking about `__autoload()` - it doesn't automatically get called by PHP - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: It depends on where you put this code. Btw, I don't recommend you to use the `__autoload` function as this function can be overridden. Better use the `spl_autoload_register` function.

Comment: `__autoload()` is part of Joomla core code so I don't want to change it, i'm trying to find a way around it.